# Website outages

Tags: ros, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the beginning of this week, there have been daily outages of the ROS website, wiki and documentation. Sometimes a few hours, sometimes multiple per day. Visualized here: https://status.ros.org/#week

Is there a reason to this? status.ros does not provide any information. Can I expect this to be an ongoing problem for a while? These outages always occur during my working hours and greatly interfer with my productivity...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274126/website-outages/) by [Jan Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/32394/jan-fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-10-26**:
Hi,
I have the same problem, but here is a small tips :
If you know the URL of the page, search it on google, click the small arrow and click "cache", you will see the cached page (you will need to do this for each link)
Or you can use : http://cachedview.com/ (who also use google's cache)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
@lmathieu: there are official wiki and docs mirrors available as well. See #q269962.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Comment on ROS Discourse by @tfoote: [Ros.org latency & availability](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-org-latency-availability/1628/9).

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2017-10-26**:
That's true :) but I always find it faster to use the google cache than searching on the mirrors, since google's result are redirecting directly on official wiki and docs.
The wiki is down, long live the (mirror)wiki !

**Comment by [Jan Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/32394/jan-fox/) on 2017-10-26**:
@gvdhoorn That actually seems to be the answer, even though it doesn't address the frequency of outages this week. But that could be random. Thanks, guys. I didn't know about mirror sites, so that is awesome to find.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
Well. It's obviously not really an answer, more a coping strategy. Ideally the mirrors aren't needed, and your question was more about what the problem is, not how to deal with it.

**Comment by [Jan Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/32394/jan-fox/) on 2017-10-26**:
Well, they said that there has been an increase in traffic, and that the servers were not built with this much traffic in mind. Seems a good enough reason to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just for the sake of completion:

The link, provided by gvdhoorn ([ROS.org latency & availability](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-org-latency-availability/1628/9)) implies that the servers are just overloaded by increased traffic, and that they are currently working on a longterm solution.

A short-term fix is found by using cached or mirror-sites.

---

Originally posted by [Jan Fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/32394/jan-fox/) with karma: 13 on 2017-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flurin4](https://answers.ros.org/users/32403/flurin4/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thanks for asking this question!
I was having the same issues and this cleared up my questions/doubts ;-)

Looking forward to when the long-term solution is online! For the meantime, I'll stick to the mirrors ;-)